# How to find the Summation S

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Given function $f(x)=\frac{9x}{9x+3}$.
Find S:
$$
S=f\left(\frac{1}{2010}\right)+f\left(\frac{2}{2010}\right)+f\left(\frac{3}{2010}\right)+\ldots+f\left(\frac{2009}{2010}\right)
$$

Comment: I think the key here is to find a general formula for $S(x, n)=f(x)+f(2x)+f(3x)...+f(nx)$. Then substitute your value $1/2010$.

Comment: I tried splitting the function f as $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{3x+1}$.Then $S(x,n)=n-\sum_i=1^n\frac{1}{3x+1}$

Comment: Is this contest math? If so, please tell us form which contest and add the tag.

Comment: No this is not contest math.Asked in placement as aptitude question.@wythagoras what are some contests ?can you tell

Answer (score 1):

We can write the sum in terms of digamma function. I don't know if it is what do you want, but surely it's a closed form. We have $$f\left(x\right)=1-\frac{1}{3x+1}
 $$ then $$f\left(\frac{k}{2010}\right)=1-\frac{2010}{3k+2010}
 $$ then we have $$\sum_{k=1}^{2009}\left(1-\frac{2010}{3k+2010}\right)=2009-\frac{2010}{3}\sum_{k=1}^{2009}\frac{1}{k+2010/3}=
 $$ $$=2009-\frac{2010}{3}\left(\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{2010}{3}+2009+1\right)-\psi^{(0)}\left(\frac{2010}{3}+1\right)\right)=1080.80766...
 $$